# Multiple Socket.io app processes cause each client socket connects and disconnects repeatedly

Tags: node.js, socket.io, haproxy

I am working on a nodejs app with Socket.io and I did a test in a single process using PM 2 and it was no errors. Then I move to our production environment(We use Google Cloud Compute Instance).

I run 3 app processes and a iOS client connects to the server. 
By the way the iOS client doesn't keep the socket connection. It doesn't send disconnect to the server. But it's disconnected and reconnect to the server. It happens continuously.

I am not sure why the server disconnects the client. 
If you have any hint or answer for this, I would appreciate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies.

I finally figured out the issue. The issue was caused by TTL of backend service in Google Cloud Load Balancer. The default TTL was 30 seconds and it made each socket connection tried to disconnect and reconnect.

So I updated the value to 3600s and then I could keep the connection.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because requests end up on a different machine rather than the one they originated from.

Straight from [Socket.io Docs: Using Multiple Nodes](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/):

> If you plan to distribute the load of connections among different processes or machines, you have to make sure that requests associated with a particular session id connect to the process that originated them.

What you need to do:

- Enable [session affinity](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#session_affinity), a.k.a *sticky sessions*.
- If you want to work with rooms/namespaces you also need to use a centralised memory store to keep track of namespace information, such as the [Redis/Redis Adapter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-website/blob/master/source/docs/using-multiple-nodes.md#passing-events-between-nodes).

But I'd advise you to read the documentation piece I posted, things might have changed a bit since the last time I've implemented something like this.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the socket.io client "tests" out the connection to its server with a couple http requests.  If you have multiple server requests and those initial http requests don't go to the exact same server each time, then the socket.io connect will never get established properly and will not switch over to webSocket and it will keep attempting to use http polling.

There are two ways to fix this.

1. You can configure your clients to just assume the webSocket protocol will work.  This will initiate the connection with one and only one http connection which will then be immediately upgraded to the webSocket protocol (with socket.io running on top of that).  In socket.io, this is a `transport` option specified with the initial connection.
2. You can configure your server infrastructure to be sticky so that a request from a given client always goes back to the exact same server.  There are lots of ways to do this depending upon your server architecture and how the load balancing is done between your servers.

If your servers are keeping any client state local to the server (and not in a shared database that all servers access), then you will need even a dropped connection and reconnect to go back to the same server and you will need sticky connections as your only solution.  You can read more about sticky sessions on the socket.io website [here](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/).